# How to update changes done on entity inside an ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have a User class which has different associations. When I create a new associated object, AClass, I do the following:

```
$object = new AClass();
$user->addAClass($object);
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

The new object is persisted (created) in the database because I have used the option `cascade: ['persist']` in the YML options file. What I fail to understand, is how to update (database wise) if I did something like this:

```
$AClasses = $user->getAClasses();
foreach ($AClasses as $object) {
    if ($object->hasCondition) {
        $object->setProperty($value);
    }
}
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

I have tried `cascade: ['refresh']` but all in void.

Comment: You really should not have to do anything for updating.  The aclasses entities should all be managed through the entity manager.  A simple $em->flush() should cause them to update.

Comment: I use FOSUB EntityManager for my User class, I could do it with two different managers, but at this point I want to know how to achieve this with one.

Comment: Not suggesting that you use two different entity managers.  I'm saying that your code should work as long as the entity manager is flushed.

Comment: Well, apparently it is not. Upon calling the updateUser() method, all changes on the User entity are reflected in the DB but associated objects (if changed) stay the same.

Comment: That just seems very unlikely.  I'd double check to verify that the ac object is actually being changed.  Maybe try from inside a command just to isolate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems fine; try updating `.yml` and set persist like:

```
//A - in double quotes
cascade: ["persist"]
```

or

```
//B - new line
cascade
    - persist
```

or

```
//C - no quotes
cascade: [ persist ]
```

It's definitely `.yml`, as mine similar code works and looks just like yours (annotations based).

Comment: Cascade persist through relationships works fine, I cannot cascade updates on entities that are in associations with the main entity